# Virtualbox won't start; /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup didn't work

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, dkms

**I couldn't find any information on this issue, so when I solved it I thought I would post it and the answer on AskUbuntu in case anyone else has the same issue.**

Virtualbox refused to start any virtual machines; told me to run `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` as root.  Doing so resulted in:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modulesError! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
 ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! DKMS tree already contains: vboxhost-4.3.18
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtualbox version was out of date compared to the dependencies.  A complete reinstall was required.  But first I backed up my dkms configuration and  removed it:

```
mkdir ~/backup_dkms
cp -r /var/lib/dkms/* ~/backup_dkms
rm -rf /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost
```

Then after a bit of fishing around, running apt update, upgrade, and autoremove, I finally ran:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

It works perfectly now.